# How to correctly place scripts files in ASP.Net MVC Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC / .net and currently doing some simple exercises. I have this javascript code where I try to register my service-worker but for some reason, it's not running. I followed all the tutorial that I can find, searched up on this but still, it doesn't work. So I'm at lost here. Thank you for helping.

```
@RenderSection("pageScripts", required: false)
@section pageScripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        console.log('test script');

        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').
                then(function (registration) {
                    // Registration was successful
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    // registration failed :(
                    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                });
        }

    </script>
}
```

Comment: what you see in your browser console ?

Comment: @Shyju Nothing. The `console.log` didn't even print that test string.

Comment: Where is this code written? inside view? same view? layout page? partial view? please share your full code

Comment: In which file are you calling `@RenderSection("pageScripts", required: false)`? I tried your code, with `@RenderSection("pageScripts", required: false)` in the file  `_Layout.cshtml`, and the `@section` in `Index.chtml`. The `console.log` call worked for me.

Comment: @JasonEvans placed these code in `_Layout.cshtml` before the `</body>` tag

Comment: @MohamadAzrie: Kindly note that for scritpts in Layout file you DO NOT need to enclose scripts in `@section pageScripts{}` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the script logic you have written is required by LayOut file you need to replace your code with below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            console.log('test script');

            if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').
                    then(function (registration) {
                        // Registration was successful
                        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        // registration failed :(
                        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
                    });
            }

        </script>
    @RenderSection("pageScripts", required: false) // NOTICE IT HAS COME DOWN
```

Kindly note that: If you are in Layout file then you DO NOT need to add

```
@section pageScripts{
}
```

On a side note, Sequence of adding scripts in your **Layout file**

```
    ....   
    ....
   </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("Any Third Party Script") 
    @Scripts.Render("Your own Custom Script file Required By Entire Application")
    <script>
       // ADD ANY Script related to LayOut Page here
        </script>
     @RenderSection("pageScripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Now if script is exclusively required by a **particular view** then..

For example: Index.csthml

```
...
</div>

@section pageScripts
{
  // Your script logic
}
```